# Alterar o tamanho de uma imagem conforme o dispositivo

Tags: css

Como eu faço para alterar o tamanho de uma imagem conforme o dispositivo? Tenho o código abaixo:

```
 <div class="header-outs" id="header">
    <div class="slider">
     <div class="callbacks_container">       
        <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">
              <li>
           <div class="slider-img one-img">
              <div class="container">
           <div class="slider-info ">
                    <div class="bottom-info">
                 <div class="col-mb-4">
                 <img src="images/logo.png" class="logoMarca">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                 <p style="font-size: 48px;
                          line-height: 80px; 
                          font-weight: 800; 
                          margin-top: -12px; 
                          text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;">SEJA BEM-VINDO <br>AO NOSSO SITE</p>
                                                  </div>
              </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
          </li>
    ....
```

No CSS tentei dessa forma, mas não consegui:

```
.logoMarca{
   width: 400px; 
   margin-top: -150px;
}
@media(max-width:991px){
   width: 280px; 
   margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Estou usando o Bootstrap 4 e já tentei o img-fluid, mas nada!

Comment: Insira a marcação de texto (HTML) completa e não se esqueça do CSS também...

Comment: Olá Thiago. O código HTML tem mais de 600 linhas e o CSS mais de 1900. O trecho que passei está isolado, ou seja, antes dele vem o início da tag body. Se faz necessário colocar isso tudo?

Comment: Quando eu digo tudo é somente a parte referente a sua pergunta, por exemplo no HTML acima pode o código até onde fecha a primeira DIV, logo o CSS você posta as classes que você utilizou nas DIVS pais da imagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use os recursos (picture, srcset e sizes) do HTML5/CSS3 (Veja o suporte no caniuse)

https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/

**OU**

Use o grid e responsividade do bootstrap com várias imagens

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="images/logo2.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <img src="images/logo3.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

**OU**

Use várias imagens e várias classes

```
   <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-fluid logo">
   <img src="images/logo2.png" class="img-fluid logo2">
   <img src="images/logo3.png" class="img-fluid logo3">

   @media(max-width:991px){
      logo { display: none }
      logo2 { display: none }
      /* demais classes */
   }
```

**OU**

Use uma div no lugar de img

```
<div class="logoMarca"></div>

.logoMarca{
   background-image: url("../images/logo.png"); /* Imagino que o CSS esteja em uma pasta separada*/
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 400px; 
   margin-top: -150px;
}
@media(max-width:991px){
   width: 280px; 
   margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: Essa solução é gambiarra, foge das boas práticas.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS pode explicar seu melhor seu comentário, o que extamente nas 3 opções "foge das boas práticas"? Qual seria a alternativa?

Answer (score 1):

A forma como vc escreveu seu `@media` está errada! Vc tem que repetir o nome da classe dentro dos `{ .logoMarca {...} }` do `@media` ou então o CSS não vai saber em qual elemento cai aplicar as propriedades. *(Seu erro nada tem a ver com Bootstrap ou img-fluid ou grid)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu código está assim veja, repare que vc não declara a classe dentro do `{ }` do `@media`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O certo é declara o CSS conforme abaixo e assim deve funcionar!

```css
.logoMarca {
 width: 400px;
 margin-top: -150px;
}

@media(max-width:991px) {
 .logoMarca {
  width: 280px;
  margin-top: -100px;
 }
}
```

```html
<img class="logoMarca" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa css grid ou flex-box 
mas caso prefira com @media coloca (min-width: 991px) pra ṕegar minimo da tela nao maximo
aqui esta meu modelo de grid caso queira da uma olhada: https://pastebin.com/P2Lz0qJz

Comment: Porte o código na sua resposta aqui, o SO tem suporte a código e pode até executar, fora que um domínio externo pode ser apagado amanhã ou ainda alguém pode não ter acesso

Comment: @media(nin-width:991px){
   width: 280px; 
   margin-top: -100px;
}